# como elimino las llaves y el igual {= } que crea el hasmap cuando compilo el codigo

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, java-8

al usar colecciones en java tengo este problema al compilar el codigo me crean estas llaves y el signo de igual y dentro agrega el codigo {= } como elimino esas llaves y ese signo de igual

```
    HashMap valor = new HashMap();

    valor.put(h,"html");

    System.out.println(valor);
```

el resultado que me arroja por la consola es {= html} y no quiero que salga así necesito que el código salga limpio solo html sin las llaves o el signo de igual espero que me puedan ayudar gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma usando el método `.get()` para obtener solamente el valor pasando como argumento la llave.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> valor = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        valor.put(1,"html");

        System.out.println(valor.get(1));
```

**Resultado:**

> html

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: @JhonOneall Estamos para ayudar. No olvides seleccionar mi respuesta como Respuesta Elegida. Saludos!.

Comment: una pregunta mas como puedo cambiar el color de los valores  que tengo en el hasmap si los quiero mostrar en un textarea o un label que tenga un color por defecto

Comment: @JhonOneall Hola, esa pregunta es candidata para un tema nuevo. Puedes crear un tema nuevo con esa preguntar agregando el código que has intentado para cambiar el color y si no te funciona, podemos ayudarte. Siempre es bueno mantener 1 solo tema en un tópico para mantener el orden y evitar confusiones. Eso que pides es fácil, seguro un poco de Google podría solucionarte el problema, de lo contrario, puedes proceder a crear un tema nuevo en el sitio.